# How to use hornetq-configuration.xml in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hornetq

We have a Spring Boot application that needs to send messages to a queue available on a remote HornetQ message broker. 
I saw that [Spring Boot supports HornetQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html) in embedded mode. However, there's only a minimal set of spring.hornetq.* properties that I can set up on application.properties of my Boot application.
The application must use a [core bridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.14.Final/user-manual/en/html/core-bridges.html) (store and forward), which is configured in a hornetq-configuration.xml file.

Question: what do I need to do to make the HornetQ embedded instance provided by Spring Boot use a hornetq-configuration.xml file that I created?

Comment: You're in the 20% case I'd say. I don't even understand why you use the embedded mode for this. How about connecting to the remote broker directly?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll Your comment has 2 questions that I can answer. Why to use the embedded mode? Because it's simpler and it follows the Spring Boot "philosophy" of not having to configure separate infrastructure elements independently. Why not connect to the remote broker directly? For improved reliability, we follow the "store and forward" approach--the sender sends messages to a local queue that automatically forwards them to the remote broker. If the sender looses connectivity, the solution still works because of the local queue (called JMS bridge our core bridge in JMS/HornetQ jargon).

Comment: It's interesting. HornetQ is deprecated so we won't do any change but I'd be interested to have a look for Artemis. Could you please create an issue in the Spring Boot tracker?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll - I'm trying to follow what you're saying and may well have 2+2=5 here, but are you saying that in the case where someone does need to connect to a HornetQ queue or topic then using the Artemis support should work transparently?

Comment: No. HornetQ is a dead project (check the web site). The code has been moved to Apache. The HornetQ support is deprecated in Spring Boot and will be removed in a future release so we're not going to invest time. But I guess the same feature exists in Artemis since it's basically somewhat the same code.